# importing variables from one file to another MATLAB

Tags: matlab, import

I have 2 matlab programs : prog1.m and prog2.m

I have to use a 2-D matrix M in both programs.

I have loaded the matrix in prog1.m (manually from  a TEXT FILE).

I have to run both the programs ~100 times (for different matrix each time) . So now i have ran prog1.m 100 times , every time with different matrix .

Now is turn of prog2.m but i don't want to load matrix manually again.

I have the saved (100 copies of) prog1.m which contains M to be used in prog2.m also . Is there a method to load M from prog2.m to prog1.m ?

I want to add some code in prog2.m which automatically loads M from prog1.m .
PS: I am very new to MATLAB

Comment: You can't "load" variables from a m-file. You could however save & load your matrix M from a mat-file. You should check the documentation on `save` and `load`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `prog1` and `prog2` are not already functions, rewrite them as functions. For example, the first line in them may look like:

`function [out1 out2] = prog1(M)`
`function out = prog2(M)`

Then, write a third function which, given a filename, loads the data, calls `prog1` and `prog2` and optionally saves the data in an appropriate form (you can use `fileparts` and `fullfile` to automatically create a new filename based on the input - e.g. given data101.txt, return data101_proc.mat.  Bare bones of such a function would be along these lines:

```
function M = prog3(fname)

M = load(fname); % or whatever method is required for loading this data 

%call prog1 and prog2
[out1 out2] = prog1(M);
out3 = prog2(M);

%make new filename
[fpath,fname2,ext] = fileparts(fname);
fname_out = fullfile(fpath, [fname2,'_out','.mat']);

%save data - depends on what outputs are and what you need to do with them later
save(fname_out, 'out1','out2','out3','M');

end
```

---

Finally, as babaea mentioned, you can use `ls` or `dir`, make up a list of the files you want to use, and create a loop which calls the above function on each file in turn.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way of doing what you want to do is to read directly from the text file using textscan:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html

If the formatting in the text files are the same, you can read from one file at a time, do your process then change the name and run again.

You can make the process more automated by changing the name of the file from which data is read dynamically in a loop around your main program. But the way to do this depends on the name of the text files.